# EXTJS Piecharts are not showing legend for dynamic data

Tags: charts, extjs, legend, extjs4.1, legend-properties

Hello I have 2 pie charts one with static data and one with dynamic. The static piechart shows the legend however the dynamic one doesnt. Its the same code for both one. Both have the same fields from the data. The data is the same.

i have set legend and showInLegend set to true

Do i need to put a rendering function or something for dynamic data piechart

Do i need to put a rendering function or something for dynamic data piechart?>

Is there some loading functionality for legend for dynamic data

Comment: Please create a working Sencha Fiddle to demonstrate your problem, so that we can try to help.

Comment: @PeterKoltai i dont have the code but its the normal legend code that works in extjs nothing fancy legend: true and showInLegend is also set to true